# how to do chain selection in datagrid?ArrayCollection with multiple filter functions

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, filter

**ArrayCollection with multiple filter functions** i want to do chain selection datagrid which means consider two textinput seaech name and age if i searched a name and get a result if i search a age the result in a datagrid should be respective to the searched name ...how to filter...

Answer (score 1):

If the DataGrid is bound to a data source that is an ArrayCollection, add a filterFunction to the ArrayCollection.

See this [post](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_to_ArrayCollection_s_filterFunction-5441.html)

Comment: i am having 3 textbox input for search consider if i search 1st text box and i got the searched data in datagird then 2nd text box search should search the 1st searched result then as well as for 3rd text box...

Comment: yup, but you still use the same filterFunction and you apply a filter according the filled text inputs.